# Help finding method of estimating regression parameters for a given performance

Tags: r, regression, sas, methodology

Pardon my ignorance, for I have very basic training in statistics, but have never taken a regression course.

I ran an experiment where participants are in one of two conditions (between subjects). They categorized an object that had values for rotation and spacing, both ranging from 1 to 100. Each participant saw 40 of those values twice. There were a lot of participants.

What I want to know is for what values of rotation (or spacing) were the participants as a whole closest to chance (.5, is it or is it not in the category) in each condition, and whether those values differ significantly from one another.

What is this process called, and what are some recommended packages or methods in SAS, R, SPSS, Mathematica, or Stata (or really anything) I could use to go about figuring it out.

Any help rephrasing the question is also very welcome.